# Generate new component while NG Live Development Server is running?

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I created an angular2 project using angular-cli. Project is working fine.
I used **ng serve** command to run it locally for development. Below is the snapshot of CLI after running the project:
[image: Angular CLI running]
Now I want to create a new component using **ng generate component** command. I have to stop it first using **Ctrl + C** and then create the component and then start it again. Its time consuming. Is there any other and better way to do it?

Comment: if you are using angular-cli with webpack, there is no need to stop the server

Comment: When you say you have to stop it, do you literally mean just because you only have one cmd window? Did you consider *opening another?*

Comment: so you are saying i should use two cli windows? commands may conflict?

Comment: @AliBaghdadi I have written the command **ng generate component** right after what is shown in picture but it didn't take any effect.

Comment: you must run it in a separate cli window, this makes no conflict

Comment: yes it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open up a second cli window to run ng serve.

Answer (score 6):

Please note if you're using VSCode you can open a second terminal window by clicking the + symbol and then toggle between them using the dropdown.

[image]

Other similar features may exist in other editors, of you can of course open a standard terminal window of your choice.